# How do I signal completion of my dataflow?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I've got a class the implements a dataflow composed of 3 steps using TPL Dataflow.

In the constructor I create the steps as TransformBlocks and link them up using LinkTo with DataflowLinkOptions.PropagateCompletion set to true. The class exposes a single method which kicks of the workflow by calling SendAsync on the 1st step. The method returns the "Completion" property of the final step of the workflow.

At the moment the steps in the workflow appear to execute as expected but final step never completes unless I explicitly call Complete on it. But doing that short-circuits the workflow and none of the steps are executed? What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MessagePipeline {
   private TransformBlock<object, object> step1;
   private TransformBlock<object, object> step2;
   private TransformBlock<object, object> step3;

   public MessagePipeline() {
      var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };
      step1 = new TransformBlock<object, object>(
        x => {
        Console.WriteLine("Step1...");
        return x;
      });
      step2 = new TransformBlock<object, object>(
        x => {
        Console.WriteLine("Step2...");
        return x;
      });
      step3 = new TransformBlock<object, object>(
        x => {
        Console.WriteLine("Step3...");
        return x;
      });

      step1.LinkTo(step2, linkOptions);
      step2.LinkTo(step3, linkOptions);
   }

   public Task Push(object message) {
      step1.SendAsync(message);
      step1.Complete();
      return step3.Completion;
   }
}
...
public class Program {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var pipeline = new MessagePipeline();
    var result = pipeline.Push("Hello, world!");
    result.ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's dataflow, not workflow

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks for the correction ;-)

Comment: The code doesn't seem related to the question. Where is the code that calls `Complete()` and where/how do you await for completion? How are the steps linked?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: okay. I've now put the code.

Comment: `ContinueWith` doesn't block execution so your program will terminate before `Console.WriteLine` can be called. You should use `result.Wait()` if you want to wait inside `Main` or `await result` elsewhere

Comment: The way `Push` is written, the pipeline can only be used for a single message. I doubt that's what you wanted. You should expose a `Complete() method that gets called *only* when the last message is sent to the pipeline, by the code that sends the messages. You should also expose the last step's Completion property as a separate property.

Comment: I want the pipeline to be used for a single message. It is important that caller can do something useful the result e.g. Wait(), ContinueWith(), etc. At the moment Wait() blocks indefinitely...which suggests to me that step3 never completes.

Comment: Perhaps this is not the best way to express what I want to do and I'm open to suggestions ultimately I need to be able to execute "n" steps. The caller must not be blocked whilst the message is being processed in the pipeline/workflow. I need a way to let the caller know when the final step is completed. Returning the Completion property looked like an obvious approach.

Comment: Forgot to mention...I'm a total newbie when it comes to TPL Dataflow ;-)

Comment: The problem is that `step3` never completes - it's a TransformBlock and no-one ever retrieves its output message. Therefore, the block can never complete. It should be an `ActionBlock`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thank you! That solves the problem ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you link the steps, you need to pass a DataflowLinkOptions with the the [PropagateCompletion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions.propagatecompletion(v=vs.110).aspx)  property set to true to propagate both completion and errors. Once you do that, calling `Complete()` on the first block will propagete completion to downstream blocks.

Once a block receives the completion event, it finishes processing then notifies its linked downstream targets.

This way you can post all your data to the first step and call `Complete()`. The final block will only complete when all upstream blocks have completed.

For example,

```
var linkOptions=new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true};
myFirstBlock.LinkTo(mySecondBlock,linkOptions);
mySecondBlock.LinkTo(myFinalBlock,linkOptions);

foreach(var message in messages)
{
    myFirstBlock.Post(message);
}
myFirstBlock.Complete();
......
await myFinalBlock.Completion;
```

PropagateCompletion isn't true by default because in more complex scenarios (eg non-linear flows, or dynamically changing flows) you don't want completion and errors to propagate automatically. You may also want to avoid automatic completion if you want to handle errors without terminating the entire flow.

Way back when TPL Dataflow was in beta the default *was* true but this was changed on RTM

**UPDATE**

The code never completes because the final step is a `TransformBlock` with no linked target to receive its output. This means that even though the block received the completion signal, it hasn't finished all its work and can't change its own Completion status.

Changing it to an `ActionBlock<object>` removes the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, that's not working as I expected. I've tried using Post instead of SendAsync I had originally (I've added a bit of the code now) but that didn't change anything. All the steps are executed but the Status on the Completion of the final step says WaitingForActivation. If call Wait() on it I'm blocked indefinitely...

Comment: You haven't posted the relevant code so it's impossible to help. This has nothing to do with *completion* though, if you call Complete on the first step and propagation is enabled, completion *will* propagate to the last step. It also doesn't matter whether you use Post or SendAsync. On the other hand, you can't expect the final step to complete immediatelly after posting to the first step, it probably hasn't received any data yet

Comment: Alternatively I could keep it as a transform block and instead of returning Completion return ReceiveAsync instead.

Comment: If i could super upvote this post i would, i was so confused at behaviors i was seeing until i read your update calling out ActionBlock should be used as a terminator as opposed to Transform because it wants to propagate. It makes so much sense stated

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly call Complete.

Comment: Do I call Complete on the 3 steps in sequence? Just the first one or just the final one?

Comment: Calling `Complete` isn't enough, completion propagation must be specified in the link options. When this is done, calling `Complete` on the first block will propagate to all downstream blocks